# Read a text file and write on different label in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, label

I want to read a text file and write the lines on different labels. Is it possible to generate labels?

I tried with four labels with label1, label2, label3, label4 names but I don't know how to create a loop to read every line of the file and write it in every different label. First line in first label, second line in second label etc.

what i've tried:

```
Do Until fread.EndOfStream
    line = fread.ReadLine()
    parti = line.Split("_")
    ora.Text = parti(1)

    data.Text = parti(2)

    If Len(parti(3)) > 10 Then
        mesaj.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(parti(3), 25) & "..."

    Else
        mesaj.Text = parti(3)

    End If

Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to create a label and put the label on the form.

```
Dim label As New Label
label.Text = "label"
Me.Controls.Add(label)
```